# net:: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT en algunos scripts de webapp de Laravel

Tags: laravel, script, aws, hosting, vite

No tengo idea de que causa este error a solo algunos de los scripts que tengo en mi proyecto ya hosteado en AWS en una VM Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Solo se muestra en estos scripts en especifico y lo demas lo carga bien:

[image: Errores en la consola de Edge]

```
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    @vite(['resources/js/jquery/jquery.min.js'])
    @vite(['resources/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'])

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    @vite(['resources/js/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js'])

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    @vite(['resources/js/sb-admin-2.min.js'])

    <!-- Page level plugins -->
    @vite(['resources/js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js'])
    @vite(['resources/js/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js'])

    <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
    <!-- @vite(['resources/js/demo/datatables-demo.js']) -->
```

Este es el codigo de los scripts. Antes de que pregunten, la ip esta bien cargada.